# Why does the command not work and no values are added to the TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently trying to figure out the MVVM pattern in wpf, and I'm writing a test application, but I ran into a problem. The CountCommand does not work. Initially, the command was synchronous and also did not work. And if you enter "Application.Current.Shutdown();" then it will close the application by clicking on the TextBlock. This means that the team itself is working and something is wrong in its body.

```
 internal class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public ICommand CountCommand{ get; set; }
    private async void Execute(object p) => await Task.Run(() => i++);
    private bool CanExecute(object p) => true;


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CountCommand = new CommendBase(Execute, CanExecute);
    }
    
}
```

The command should add `1` when I click on the Textblock

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the ViewModel part

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Lesson_1.MainWindow"     mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_Lesson_1"
        xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:MVVM_Lesson_1.ViewModle"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="AliceBlue">
    <Window.DataContext>
      <vm:MainWindowViewModel></vm:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock 
            
            Margin="20"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding Path= i}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="50"
            Width="150">
            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding 
                    Gesture="LeftClick"
                    Command="{Binding Path=CountCommand}"/>
            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Add 1 to what? Something in the view or just `i` ?

Comment: How did you bind your xaml file to the view model? Post the xaml part where you have declared binding to the viewmodel. According to the question itself, it would be good if you post the whole xaml file. Probably you have binding issues for command and for counter.

Comment: No, everything is fine with the binding. Because the values that I set from the code are shown, but when pressed it does not increase.

Comment: Your view model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Link to a disk with xaml -https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KRbCVi_gfguAB2LBqqNDoqcXoX3oxD5t/view?usp=sharing